# Laravel Middleware not executing functions

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I have this Locale middleware which sets language based from settings on DB

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $HQ = Branch::where('is_hq', 1)->where('is_active', 1)->first();

        $Company = GlobalVariable()->branch($HQ)->all()->whereIn('group', array(1, 3, 9))->keyBy('key');
        $locale = strtolower($Company['bi__language']->value);

        if ($locale === 'eng') {
            \App::setlocale('en');
        } else {
            \App::setlocale($locale);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

but i need to get the branch where the current user is so i need to get the **Auth::id()** first so i changed my code to this to access Auth.

```
     public function handle($request, Closure $next)
     {
        $response = $next($request);

        $HQ = Branch::where('is_hq', 1)->where('is_active', 1)->where('user_id', \Auth::id())->first();

        $Company = GlobalVariable()->branch($HQ)->all()->whereIn('group', array(1, 3, 9))->keyBy('key');
        $locale = strtolower($Company['bi__language']->value);

        if ($locale === 'eng') {
            \App::setlocale('en');
        } else {
            \App::setlocale($locale);
        }

        return $response;
    }
```

Now i am getting the current user logged in but the problem is it is not executing this block of code

```
if ($locale === 'eng') {
   \App::setlocale('en');
} else {
    \App::setlocale($locale);
}
```

**Kernel.php**

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class,
];
```

> Note: the code wihout Auth is executing this block of code but the second isn't

Am i missing something here?

Comment: What do you mean by "not executing"? What have you tried to check for this?

Comment: the first code is changing my locale (language) but the second with Auth not changing anything

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: only used dd() to check. the code will go through inside that if block but not executing that \App::setlocale($locale);

Comment: however the first code without Auth the code is executing \App::setlocale($locale);

Comment: `$locale = strtolower($Company['bi__language']->value)` did you check that assigned HQ has valid locale for every user?

Comment: yeah checked that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second one you have

```php
$response = $next($request);
```

at the very beginning, so the code will execute at `response`.

You need to do something like this:

```php
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $HQ = Branch::where('is_hq', 1)->where('is_active', 1)->where('user_id', \Auth::id())->first();
        $Company = GlobalVariable()->branch($HQ)->all()->whereIn('group', array(1, 3, 9))->keyBy('key');
        $locale = strtolower($Company['bi__language']->value);

        if ($locale === 'eng') {
            \App::setlocale('en');
        } else {
            \App::setlocale($locale);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

If you do not have the `auth()->user()`, this is because the place that you register the middleware is not correct.

The global middleware stack runs prior to the session being started and authentication details being available.

Define this at the bottom of the 'web' group or in your route middleware.

```php
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: i used $response = $next($request); so that \Auth::id() won't return null

Comment: can you help me about that issue on my first one? because it returns Auth::id() as null

Comment: @Franz I think that's because how you register your middleware, check my updated answer. or you can show us your middleware file if you want.

Comment: @Franz Instead of ``Auth::id()`` use ``Auth::user()->id``

Comment: @OMiShah i tried all of the following => Auth::user(), Auth::id(), auth()->user()->id , etc

Comment: @AndySong my middleware is registered on Kernel.php not on routes

Comment: @Franz the order is important, all middlewares are in that file, if you do not know what I am talking about, just provide the whole file.

Comment: what specific file u want?

Comment: @Franz where you registered your middleware. Kernel.php

Comment: @Franz you need to put it in the `$middlewareGroups` array within `'web'` group. I also updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for the time , i tried what u suggested but it still returrns Auth::user() as null

Comment: @Franz did you login?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220602/discussion-between-franz-and-andy-song).